# xml parsing dom file not found

Tags: java, android, xml, dom

i'm trying to make a simple dom writer and reader in internal storage

this is the code

```
protected void write_xml_file(String file_name) {
    //if (file_name == null) file_name = "spells.xml";
    FileOutputStream fos;
    try {
        fos = openFileOutput(file_name, Context.MODE_APPEND);
        XmlSerializer serializer = Xml.newSerializer();
        serializer.setOutput(fos, "UTF-8");
        serializer.startDocument(null, Boolean.valueOf(true));
        serializer.setFeature("http://xmlpull.org/v1/doc/features.html#indent-output", true);
        serializer.startTag(null, "spells");
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            serializer.startTag(null, "spell");
            serializer.text("a" + j);
            serializer.endTag(null, "spell");
        }
        serializer.endDocument();
        serializer.flush();
        fos.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}

protected void read_xml_file(String file_name) {
    try {
        File fXmlFile = new File(file_name);
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder = null;
        dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
        NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("spells");


        for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {

            Node nNode = nList.item(temp);

            //System.out.println("\nCurrent Element :" + nNode.getNodeName());

            if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

                Element eElement = (Element) nNode;

                //System.out.println("spell id : " + eElement.getAttribute("id"));
                //System.out.println("name : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("firstname").item(0).getTextContent());
                //System.out.println("description : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("firstname").item(0).getTextContent());
                //System.out.println("school : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("lastname").item(0).getTextContent());

            }
        }


        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SAXException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

for to write no problem, the file is wrote correctly

when i try to read i have an error: file not found

can someone help me?

thanks

Mauro

Answer (score 0):

While storing your are storing in the internal file directory, but while retrieving you are just giving just the name

Example, its writing in data/data/[package name]/files/[file_name]
but you are trying to retrieve from [file_name].

So instead of getting directly from file name while read xml file, you can try like this,

```
File fXmlFile = new File(context.getFilesDir() + File.separator + file_name);
```

> Note: you can get `getFilesDir()` from Context, so try to send context
>   in parameter.